# store an object in parent object through javascript

Tags: javascript, object, nested-object

I have an signup form asking firstname, lastname, email, password and I have to save them as object where object key should be firstname like below structure.

```
firstname(i.e charan ) : {
firstname : 'charan',
lastname : 'naidu',
email: charaN@gmail.com,
password : 12344,
}
```

Comment: OK, so you do `Accounts.sai = { slitID... }`.  Right?

Comment: Sounds good. What's the problem?

Comment: Tried it, Accounts.sai.slitID = '124343434'; got this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'slitID')

Comment: You have to set `Accounts.sai` to something before you can set `Accounts.sai.slitID` to something. The `sai` object doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I need to dynamically add sai object through javascript input and then add sai details accordingly to its object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created the `Accounts` variable, you can then create a new object on it by just giving it a value. `Accounts.sai = {  ...  }`

```js
const Accounts = {
    chinnu: {
        slitID: 3452309,
        fistName: 'chinnu',
        lastName: 'karam',
        email: 'absdf@gmail.com',
        password: 'abscs*1',
    }
}

Accounts.sai = {
    slitID: 3423409,
    fistName: 'sai',
    lastName: 'athul',
    email: 'athulsai@gmail.com',
    password: 'silaka*1',
}

console.log(Accounts);
```

Comment: I need it to be added through javascript, can I expect js code ?

Comment: This is javascript code. Press the "Run code snippet" button and the code will run and show you the complete `Accounts` object.

Comment: I have an signup form asking firstname, lastname, email, password and I have to save them as object where object key should be firstname like below structure.

firstname(i.e charan ) : {
firstname : 'charan',
lastname : 'naidu',
email: charaN@gmail.com,
password : 12344,
}